# pybind11 conflict with GetModuleFileName

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to let python call an existing C++ module (library). The connection is through, however, in the C++ library, ::GetModuleFileName (Visual Studio) is called to to determine the physical path of the loaded module as it is run in C++. But when I call the library from python (Jupyter Notebook) through pybind11, the physical path of python.exe is returned. How can I configure or change to make sure the physical path of the C++ library is obtained?

The C++ code is like this:
Lib.h

```
#pragma once

void run();
```

Lib.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <windows.h>
#include "libloaderapi.h"

#include "Lib.h"

void run()
{
    char buf[1024];
    ::GetModuleFileName(0, buf, sizeof(buf));

    std::ofstream of;
    of.open("logging.txt");

    if (!of.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open logging.txt");
    }

    of << "The loaded module is " << buf << std::endl;
}
```

The pybind11 interface code:
Direct.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include "Lib.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

// wrap c++ function
void wrapper() {
    run();
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(run_app, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 plugin";

    m.def("run", &wrapper, "Run C++ Application");
}
```

The pybind11 setup file:
setup.py

```
#from distutils.core import setup, Extension
#from distutils import sysconfig

from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

# The following is for GCC compiler only.
#cpp_args = ['-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++', '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7']
cpp_args = []

sfc_module = Extension(
    'run_app',
    sources=['Direct.cpp', 
             'Lib.cpp'],
    include_dirs=[pybind11.get_include(), '.'],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=cpp_args,
    )

setup(
    name='run_app',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python package with RunApp C++ extension (PyBind11)',
    ext_modules=[sfc_module],
)
```

To build:

> python setup.py build

The python code calling this library:
py_run_app.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('build\lib.win-amd64-3.7'))

from run_app import run
run()
```

After the run:

> python py_run_app.py

In the logging.txt
The loaded module is C:....\python.exe

What I want to see is the physical location of the module.

Comment: Show code; as long as the GetModuleFileName call is located in the c++ library it should return the right path.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) seems to say that when called with the first parameter of NULL, you get the path to the executable.

Comment: It behaves as documented, verify that in the MSDN. I think there are actual ways to get a handle to the "current" module. Barring that, you might be able to store the handle when `DllMain()` is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Module" in Windows parlance is a DLL or an executable file loaded to be a part of a process. Each module has a *module handle*; by convention, the special handle `NULL` signifies the executable file used to create the process.

`GetModuleFileName` requires module handle as the first argument. You pass `0`, you get back the name of the module with the special handle `NULL`, i.e. the executable. This is fully expected.

In order to get the file name of a DLL, you need to find out what its handle is. You can find the handle of the current module:

```
HMODULE handle;
static char local;
bool ok = GetModuleHandleEx (GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
                             (LPCSTR)&local,
                             &handle);
```

`local` can be any function or static/extern variable in the current module. [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexa).

Comment: This is very helpful and resolves my matter. Thank you!